# Spring MVC - How to process tree hierachy using RequestMapping annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I have below urls to be processed through RequestMapping annotation.

http://localhost:8080/model/switch
http://localhost:8080/model/switch//card/
http://localhost:8080/model/switch//card//port

I tried `@RequestMapping(value = "/model/*", method=RequestMethod.POST)`, it works only for http://localhost:8080/model/switch and it does not work for other two. It seems spring splits / and cuts remaining uris.

So how to match a tree using @RequestMapping? Also i need to get this url as a parameter in rest method. I used @PathVariable and it works for first input. For the second and third input, it does not work.

Comment: Try to use `model/**`

Comment: excellent, it works. to get url HttpServletReqeust.getServletpath() is used